# What does クタる means?

Tags: word-usage, reading-comprehension

[image]

The character is cooking and he says this.

絹さや is "snow peas" at least and ラストlast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

クタる is associated with the onomatopoeia くたくた, which describes a stuff simmered and become too soft to keep original shape (in cooking context). So overall, he says snow peas are easy to be くたくた and thus put them in the pan last.